# Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting a new issue on my Wordpress page that I haven't seen before. The theme is supported but their obsolete plugin they made me install isn't, go figure. Anyways, I get this error on the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in /photography-custom-post/tg-shortcode.php:782 Stack trace: #0
```

From the above file on line 782:

```php
$return_html.= '<div class="'.esc_attr($column_class).' static filterable gallery_type animated'.esc_attr($key+1).'">';
```

I don't know enough about coding to diagnose this.

Comment: Pretty clear error? it says `string + int` are an unsupported combination for `+`. Which is true: this code is trying to add the number `1` to the string value in `$key`, which makes no sense, and you'll have to turn that key into a number first.

Comment: Makes sense. I removed the "+1" and the pages work again. Thank you for solving such a simple issue!

Comment: In case the `+1` is essential for your software to function you could use `1+$key`, which will work as long as `$key` contains a number, even if it is a string.